# Параметры запуска runfcgi

Tags: nginx, django, сервер

Объясните пожалуйста, различия в **runfcgi** для **method=prefork/threaded**, и **maxrequests**, **maxspare** и т.д. В общем параметрах этой команды, а то запускаю не вникая, хотелось бы понять.
И если может кто видел где тесты, с какими параметрами лучше работают сайты под большой нагрузкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**method** — prefork или threaded, prefork создает отдельный процесс(колво указано в min-maxspare) для запроса, threaded создает поток для запроса.Рекомендуется prefork ввиду GIL, а также того, что в UNIX и POSIX-совместимых ОС создание процесса дешевле создания потока.

**maxrequests** — Количество обработанных запросов перед тем как чайлд(тред) будет убит и создан новый взамен( ставишь ноль и убиваться не будут). Зачем их убивать другой вопрос, можно задать этот вопрос на хэш коде.

**maxspare/minspare**— макс и мин количество запасных тредов/процессов.При старте сервера у вас будет minspare процессов, при нагрузке оно будет рости до maxspare.

**maxchildren** — жесткий лимит на количество тредов/процессов.

Под большой нагрузкой не стоит использовать fastcgi-runcgi, посмотрите в сторону [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/).

Comment: Спасибо. Всё чётко и ясно.